# How to view value of segue.identifier in debugger?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I have a breakpoint on the `if` line below. This code is in `ViewControllerOne`. The push is to `ViewControllerTwo`. Once the breakpoint is hit, how do I view the value of `segue.identifier` without using an `NSLog`?

When I hover over identifier, nothing pops up. Hovering over `seque` just displays an `NSObject` in the debugger.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"submitButtonToSeque"]) {
        AAViewControllerTwo *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

Using an `NSLog` I can see the value output into the debugger. But I'd like to avoid the `NSLog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on the if statement

[image]

As you type in the console, intellisense will help you autocomplete:

[image]

the command is `po <object>`:

[image]

Comment: @4thSpace I am not sure to be honest, I suspect the value of the identifier is in the storyboard at that time? hover does not always work so I would use `po` to debug

Answer (score 0):

Show the `Debugger` (`XCode>View/Debug Area`).
Show the `Variables View` (on the debug area, at the bottom right, click on the icon to show the left panel).
Once your code hits the breakpoint, right click on the `segue` var, `print description`

Comment: When I right click on the segue variable, I don't see print description anywhere.